# Wilcard domain with DigitalOcean and Nginx to catch all requests to subdomains

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean

I have a large list of subdomains and the list continues to grow.

I recently started using Digital Ocean and I need to recreate the list of subdomains but the process of creating them one by one using the DNS Server control panel is very time consuming and besides that, whenever I need to create a new subdomain I will have to do it manually.

I'm trying to create a wildcard domain so that all subdomains are captured by the DNS server and then each one is redirected to the specific service.

The service that will be used is Odoo and it will work together with Nginx.

What I've done so far:

- I registered the new domain name (example.com);
- Updated the Domain Name Servers to point to Digital Ocean (ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com);

In the DNS control panel at Digital Ocean, I created the following DNS records:

A       *.example.com     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    3600

CNAME   [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)   example.com        43200

A       example.com       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    3600

NS example.com ns1.digitalocean.com 1800

NS example.com ns2.digitalocean.com 1800

NS example.com ns3.digitalocean.com 1800

For the records "example.com" and "www.example.com" everything seems to be working because when I ping I see that the traffic is redirected to the Digital Ocean droplet.

In Nginx I created a server block and included as servers:

server {

```
 ...
 server_name example.com www.example.com *.example.com .example.com test.example.com;

 ...
```

}

With this configuration I can easily access the Odoo server using the addresses: example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but when I try to access the address "**test.example.com**" I cannot access the server.

Surely it will be necessary to perform some more step that passed me and I didn't find in my searches?

Answer (score 0):

I found that during the tests I had placed a record in the /etc/hosts file with:

127.0.0.1 test.example.com

After removing this record, everything is working as expected.